# Oddly shaped buttons

Tags: swift, swift2

How can I set an image as a button but have the boundaries of the image be the boundaries of the button as well? i.e. a trapezoid that appears on the users screen but the user can only click within the trapezoid. 
I know this exists in Objective C as OBShapedButton but I would like to do the same using swift. 
 Thanks so much

Comment: You could either use OBShapedButton, or have a look at https://gist.github.com/clmntcrl/8e4cab3ed7d1e7da47e7 which is the Swift equivalent.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help.